# Not able to load nested Json Array

Tags: android, arrays, json

My Json Value is

```
{"candidateName":"Check","success":true,"candidateWorkExperience":"[{\"candidateWorkExperienceId\":7486,\"candidateBiographyRef\":{\"primaryKey\":98567,\"percent\":0.0,\"specialization\":0,\"rating\":0,\"description\":\"Check\",\"properties\":{},\"secondaryKey\":0,\"start\":0,\"limit\":0,\"noOfStud\":0,\"typingTest\":false,\"isPostGrad\":false},\"designation\":\"Check\",\"company\":\"Check\",\"startDate\":\"Jan 1, 2012\",\"endDate\":\"Jan 1, 2014\",\"workTypeMasterRef\":{\"primaryKey\":2,\"percent\":0.0,\"specialization\":0,\"rating\":0,\"description\":\"Permanent\",\"properties\":{},\"secondaryKey\":0,\"start\":0,\"limit\":0,\"noOfStud\":0,\"typingTest\":false,\"isPostGrad\":false},\"achivements\":\"Check\",\"candidateRecordStatus\":\"EXISTING\",\"currentCompany\":\"false\"}]"}
```

I am trying to pass the same by

```
JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("candidateWorkExperience");
```

But I am getting  `org.json.JSON.typeMismatch` exception.

Can any one suggest how to load the json data into the array.

Comment: show your php code where you are generating json

Comment: Try removing the " before and after []... something like "candidates":[{...},{...}]

Comment: `candidateWorkExperience` is being saved as an object and not as an array

Comment: @raj who says it is PHP? But I agree, the error is in the generation of the json, so post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you put "[]" which js is interpreting as a string not an array.

The arrays are enclosed by [] with no ".

Try the next json and let me know if this fix your problem:

```
{
"candidateName": "Check",
"success": true,
"candidateWorkExperience": [
    {
        "candidateWorkExperienceId": 7486,
        "candidateBiographyRef": {
            "primaryKey": 98567,
            "percent": 0.0,
            "specialization": 0,
            "rating": 0,
            "description": "Check",
            "properties": {

            },
            "secondaryKey": 0,
            "start": 0,
            "limit": 0,
            "noOfStud": 0,
            "typingTest": false,
            "isPostGrad": false
        },
        "designation": "Check",
        "company": "Check",
        "startDate": "Jan1, 2012",
        "endDate": "Jan1, 2014",
        "workTypeMasterRef": {
            "primaryKey": 2,
            "percent": 0.0,
            "specialization": 0,
            "rating": 0,
            "description": "Permanent",
            "properties": {

            },
            "secondaryKey": 0,
            "start": 0,
            "limit": 0,
            "noOfStud": 0,
            "typingTest": false,
            "isPostGrad": false
        },
        "achivements": "Check",
        "candidateRecordStatus": "EXISTING",
        "currentCompany": "false"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I made a mistake while creating the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not correct, your "candidateWorkExperience" parameter is not a JSONArray but a JSONString.

Paste your JSON [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

And you will see how you JSON is parsed.

Cheers !